# How I can retrieve DeployOptions with VS Code?

Tags: apex, metadata, vs-code

How i can retrieve DeployOptions metadata with VS Code and edit it? Or How I can deploy a class to Production without running any tests?

Comment: Deploy a class without running any tests? Not possible. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to delete a class, test class is failing. So need some kind of workaround.I am using VS Code.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on [Destructive Change Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeployOptions` is not a Metadata API entity you can retrieve and edit. It is an object passed to the [`deploy()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) Metadata API call.

If deploying using the Salesforce DX CLI (`sfdx`), such as via [`force:source:deploy`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm), you use the options

```
-l | --testlevel TESTLEVEL
```

and

```
-r | --runtests RUNTESTS
```

options to control which tests you wish to run during deployment. `-r` is used only if you specify `-l RunSpecifiedTests`. Running specified tests *may* in some circumstances allow you to perform deployments that are otherwise blocked by issues with existing unit tests.

There is no way in any API to perform an Apex deployment to a production Salesforce org without running tests, nor should there be.